# Node execute PS script prepends options that fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

`exec('command', {'shell':'powershell.exe'}, (error, stdout, stderr) => { ... }` fails with the following error:

```
/d : The term '/d' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ /d /s /c command
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/d:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is prepending the `/d /s /c` and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your symptom implies that **you're using an *old* Node.js version**.
- **Upgrade to at least `v11.15.0`** to make your code work.

**In versions before that, the command-line options [`/d /s /c` were *invariably* used](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_shell_requirements), irrespective of what executable you specified for `shell`** - and since `powershell.exe` doesn't understand these options, commands invariably failed.

Since v11.15.0, **[`-c` is now used for any shell *other* than `cmd.exe`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_shell_requirements)**, which PowerShell *does* understand.

You can use the following **test command** from PowerShell to see if your Node.js version is recent enough:

```sh
# Run from PowerShell.
# If your Node.Js version is recent enough, you'll see PowerShell's version info,
# otherwise, an error will occur.
node -pe "child_process.execSync('`$PSVersionTable', { shell: 'powershell.exe' }).toString()"
```